# return specific value from id column to create new column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this example data to use it to make it easier

```
CREATE TABLE example (
id_ TEXT ,
product TEXT ,
price numeric (10));

INSERT INTO example (id_, product, price)
values
('1a','Soap', 200),
('1a','Conditioner', 300),
('1a','Shampoo', 250),
('1a','Soap', 100),
('2a','Toothbrush', 150),
('2a','Soap', 200),
('2a','Mouthwash',350),
('3a','Shampoo',250),
('3a','Perfume',400);
```

Normally, most of all will use this code

```
SELECT id_, product, sum(price)total  
FROM example     
group by id_, product  
order by id_, product;
```

so it will get this kind of output

```
id_     product     total
1a  Conditioner     300
1a  Shampoo         250
1a  Soap            300
2a  Mouthwash       350
2a  Soap            200
2a  Toothbrush      150
3a  Perfume         400
3a  Shampoo         250
```

is there any way to make it like this, maybe use case when to make it simple ?
will give 1 if different id_, and give 0 if same id_,

```
id_     product     total   tot_cust
1a  Conditioner     300     1
1a  Shampoo         250     0
1a  Soap            300     0
2a  Mouthwash       350     1
2a  Soap            200     0
2a  Toothbrush      150     0
3a  Perfume         400     1
3a  Shampoo         250     0
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the expected output.

Comment: I don't understand it either, but maybe adding a `COUNT(*)` in the select might point to the desired solution?

Comment: the final result needs to know how many customers, but they need to count it manually by using this new column

Comment: Where do the customers come from? There is nothing in your table that identifies them.

Comment: That id_ column is the customer, every customer has a unique id. I know the simplest way to find total customer or unique id just with count(distinct id_), but I need to manually add it like the output that i've provided, is there any ideas how to do it? First thing that come to my mind is maybe using case when or lag or lead function, will return 1 if it's different than previous value, 0 if it's same as the previous value but I dont know how to make it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT
  id_,
  product,
  sum(price) total,
  (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_ ORDER BY product) = 1)::int AS tot_cust
FROM example     
GROUP BY id_, product  
ORDER BY id_, product
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks to you. This helps me a lot. This works best in my case